# Unable to add second child in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Unable to add second child in `Recyclerview` I am passing two different arrays to `RecyclerAdapter` to display two child layout with different data and views.Is there any solution to add different child layout using same header layout.I added horizontal `Recyclerview` in vertical `Recyclerview` and I want to display details like I attached the image

```
private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
     RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter();

     int[] images = new int[]{
         R.drawable.finance,
         R.drawable.business,
         R.drawable.financejob,
         R.drawable.ecomchallenges
     };

     ArrayList<ChildView> childViews = new ArrayList<>();
     childViews.add(new ChildView(images[0], "The \"Best\" Startup Pitch Deck - How To Raise Venture Capital", "$100"));
     childViews.add(new ChildView(images[1], "An Entire MBA in 1 Course:Award Winning Business School Prof", "$100"));
     childViews.add(new ChildView(images[2], "What Finance Job is for You? Explanation of 14 Finance Roles", "$100"));
     childViews.add(new ChildView(images[3], "Learn To Build Beautiful HTML5 And CSS3 Websites In 1 Month", "$100"));

     int[] courseImage = new int[] {
         R.drawable.php,
         R.drawable.development,
         R.drawable.web,
         R.drawable.java
     };

     ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes = new ArrayList<>();
     courseByTypes.add(new CourseByType("Technology", courseImage[0]));
     courseByTypes.add(new CourseByType("Business", courseImage[1]));
     courseByTypes.add(new CourseByType("Photography", courseImage[2]));
     courseByTypes.add(new CourseByType("Development", courseImage[3]));
     Log.d("","Above adapter");
     recyclerAdapter.addItem(new GroupView("Business", childViews));
     Log.d("","Below Child");
     recyclerAdapter.addCourseByType(new CourseByHeader("Technology", courseByTypes));
     Log.d("","Below Course");
     recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

 }
```

This is the main fragment where I set the values to two different

```
arraylist ArrayList<ChildView> childViews = new ArrayList<>()
```

and

```
ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes = new ArrayList<>()
```

Values of child views are passing properly but `CourseByType` values are not passing.This is the adapter class for this fragment class.

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<PassValues> containerArrayList;

    ArrayList<GroupView> groupViews;
    ArrayList<CourseByHeader>courseByHeaders;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.group_title, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(){
        containerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        groupViews = new ArrayList<>();
        courseByHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addContainer(PassValues container){
        containerArrayList.add(container);


    }
    public void addItem(GroupView groupView){
        Log.d("","Inside Group method");
        groupViews.add(groupView);
    }
    public void addCourseByType(CourseByHeader courseByHeader){
        Log.d("","Inside Course method");
        courseByHeaders.add(courseByHeader);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("", "Pass Values out of IF" + position);
        ChildViewAdapter childViewAdapter = new ChildViewAdapter();
        if(position == 0){
            GroupView groupView = groupViews.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(groupView.getTitle());
            Log.d("", "Passing Values" + groupView.getTitle());
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            childViewAdapter.addChild(groupView.getChildViewList());
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(childViewAdapter);
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            CourseByHeader courseByHeader = courseByHeaders.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(courseByHeader.getTitle());
            Log.d("", "Passing Values" + courseByHeader.getTitle());
            holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.recyclerView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
            holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            childViewAdapter.addCourse(courseByHeader.getCourseByTypes());
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(childViewAdapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(getItemViewType(0) == TYPE_HEADER)
        return groupViews.size() ;
        if (getItemViewType(1) == TYPE_ITEM)
            return courseByHeaders.size();
        else return -1;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_title);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.group_recycler);

        }
    }
}
```

This `RecyclerAdapter` contains one `RecyclerView` in that first row has one image and 3 `textviews` and 2nd row has 1 `ImageView` and 1 `TextView`. At position first,one image and 3 textviews are shown but it's not going on 2nd view

This is the view I getting after run on emulator.

[image]

This are two child for `RecyclerViews`

**ChildView.java**

```
public class ChildView {

    int image;
    String course, price;

    public ChildView(int image, String course, String price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.course = course;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

**CourseByType.java**

```
public class CourseByType {

    String courseName;
    int courseImage;

    public CourseByType(String courseName, int courseImage) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseImage = courseImage;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public int getCourseImage() {
        return courseImage;
    }
}
```

**CourseByHeader.java**

```
public class CourseByHeader {

    String title;
    ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes;

    public CourseByHeader(String title, ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.courseByTypes = courseByTypes;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public ArrayList<CourseByType> getCourseByTypes() {
        return courseByTypes;
    }
}
```

**GroupView.java**

```
public class GroupView {
    String title;
    ArrayList<ChildView> childViewList;

    String courseBy;
    ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes;

    public GroupView(String title, ArrayList<ChildView> childViewList) {
        this.title = title;
        this.childViewList = childViewList;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public ArrayList<ChildView> getChildViewList() {
        return childViewList;
    }
}
```

Groupview and CouseByType class have title and child list for recycleradapter

**ChildViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ChildViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList<ChildView> childViewList;
    ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByTypes;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class GroupHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ImageView iamView;
        public TextView course, price;
        public GroupHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iamView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_image);
            course = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_by);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        }
    }

    public void addCourse(ArrayList<CourseByType> courseByType){
        courseByTypes = courseByType;
    }
    public void addChild(ArrayList<ChildView> childView){
        childViewList = childView;
    }

    public class Course extends ViewHolder {

        public ImageView courseTypeImage;
        public TextView courseType;

        public Course(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            courseTypeImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_image);
            courseType = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_name_course);
        }
    }

    public ChildViewAdapter() {
        childViewList = new ArrayList<>();
        courseByTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
        View v;
        if(viewType == TYPE_HEADER){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
            return new GroupHolder(v);
        }if(viewType == TYPE_ITEM){
            v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.type_of_courses, parent, false);
            return new Course(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof GroupHolder){
            Log.d("","instance of Group Holder");
            ChildView childView = childViewList.get(position);
            ((GroupHolder)holder).iamView.setImageResource(childView.getImage());
            ((GroupHolder)holder).course.setText(childView.getCourse());
            ((GroupHolder)holder).price.setText(childView.getPrice());
            return;
        }
        if(holder instanceof Course){
            Log.d("","instance of Course ");
            CourseByType courseByType = courseByTypes.get(position);
            ((Course)holder).courseTypeImage.setImageResource(courseByType.getCourseImage());
            ((Course)holder).courseType.setText(courseByType.getCourseName());
            return;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int size;
        if(childViewList.size()>0){
            return size = childViewList.size();
        }else return size = courseByTypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(childViewList.size() != 0 && childViewList.size()>0){
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        }else return TYPE_ITEM;
    }


}
```

This childview adapter has two view types first is one image and 3 text and second view type contain one image and one text.When I pass values from fragment only first view type get displayed and second view type not gets value from fragment.

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code. It is too difficult for a person to understand what you are looking for

Comment: Actually I made classes,adapters for each layout.Please give me solution what I use to display the output As like I attached the image in question.It's urgent I tried lots of solution but didn't get

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong:
1. You want two separate types of views- assume v1 & v2
2. For v1 you want to use data of class c1 and v2 data of class c2.

Comment: please give solution what I use to display output like that

Comment: yes sir. I use horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview.vertical for header title and horizontal for displaying child layout

Comment: ok but in adapter how to set them at different position in above code I tried same

Comment: Is the horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview working? Is it scrollable vertially and horizontally?

Comment: Yes sir. vertical scroll vertically and hozrizontal recycler horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show multiple different views in a recyclerview, you have to override `getItemViewType()` in the recyclerview adapter.

```
 //getItemViewType enables dynamic viewholder creation
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //you will need to add a integer with variable name viewTypeCode
    //for view1 set viewTypeCode = 100 and for view2 set viewTypeCode = 200
    viewTypeCode = itemList.get(position).getViewTypeCode();
    return viewTypeCode;
}
```

This is how the `onCreateViewHolder` will be different for multiple viewtypes. You will have to modify yours like this

```
@Override
public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 100: return new FeedViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.v1, parent, false),100);
        case 200: return new FeedViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.v2, parent, false),200);
    }
    return null;
}
```

`OnBindViewHolder` will be similarly modified

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
     viewTypeCode = itemList.get(position).getViewTypeCode();
    switch ( viewTypeCode) {
        case 100:
           //your code for v1

        case 200:
            //your code for v2
    }
}
```

Similarly the ViewHolder class is modified

```
class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   //declare variables here
  public FeedViewHolder(View v, int viewType) {
        super(v);
        switch (viewType) {
        //instead of itemView.findViewById you will have to use v.findViewById
        case 100:
           //your code for v1

        case 200:
            //your code for v2
    }
}
```

For further reference refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579718/5512020) SO answer

Don't pass two separate list.Make a custom class like this-

```
class MyClass {
   int viewTypeCode;
   CustomClass1 c1;
   CustomClass2 c2;

//add the setter getter
}
```

In your activity while preparing the data.

```
List<MyClass> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
//put whatever logic you need to make the order of the list
//if CustomClass1 object is put then setViewTypeCode(100), setCustomClass2 = null
//if CustomClass2 object is put then setViewTypeCode(200), setCustomClass1 = null
```

After data is built, then send this to the adapter.

Comment: For header view where I put condition in same adapter or not and How I pass data from each class that I made  for two views

Comment: How to pass two lists with different data in recycle adapter

Comment: where I pass and set header title to  view v1 and view v2 .

Comment: after fetching customClass1 object then how to set value using that object.there are 5 feilds in CustomClass1 and also setter and getter for each

Comment: i am get confused in setting data.How to do that

Comment: First create a customclass1 object c1... put all the values to it. Then `myClass.setCustomClass1(c1)`

Comment: i add the values to both class

Comment: //if CustomClass1 object is put then setViewTypeCode(100), setCustomClass2 = null
//if CustomClass2 object is put then setViewTypeCode(200), setCustomClass1 = null

Comment: how to do that with code.How to check customclass1 object is put and then set viewTypecode=100 and set customClass2=null

Comment: This will depend on how you are getting the data for the two classes...it would be better if you ask a separate SO question asking about how it should be structured...this will depend from case to case

Comment: List<MyClass> itemList  = new ArrayList<>();
        MyClass myClass=new MyClass();

        ChildView childView=new ChildView(" Paint Exhibition","" + "XYZ","09-10-2016","15-10-2016",covers[0]);
         myClass.setC1(childView);

Comment: in my fragment I declared like this

Comment: Yes...now after this add lines myClass.setViewTypeCode(100); myClass.setC2(null); itemList.add(myClass);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867392/how-to-add-multiple-child-in-recycler-i-have-2-different-view-types-but-my-seco                                       Please sir response to this question also

Comment: If my answer helped, can you please mark it correct?

Comment: where I add header layout ?In viewtype using position zero or any other option.I want to just change child layout header title layout should same for all child

Comment: Just want to change horizontal recyclerview (child)layout.Please help me

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are saying...your code would have changed significantly ... So can you ask a separate stackoverflow question

Comment: http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: I want output like that but in above link child layout are same